# difference between two times in java

Tags: java, date, jcombobox

I have searched and found a lot of different things but none that actually help to get what I am looking for. I have two JComboBoxes in which the user can select different times. For example lets say 8:00, and 17:30. Now I want to be able to display the difference between those times, so in this case it would be 9.5. I want it to be in the 9.5, and not 9:30. But my code is doing 9.3, because it is just converting my string to a double.

Any help would be great

```
public void displaytotal() {
    Object sunBobj, sunEobj, mon, tues, wed, thur, fri, sat;
    double totalD;

    sunBobj = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
    sunEobj = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();
    String sunB = sunBobj.toString();
    String sunE = sunEobj.toString();
    try {
        double sundB = Double.parseDouble(sunB.replace(":", "."));
        double sundE = Double.parseDouble(sunE.replace(":", "."));
        totalD = ((sundE - sundB)) * 24;

        String totalS = "" + totalD;
        jLabel17.setText(totalS);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you select times across multiple dates (and do you have to worry about daylight savings time)?  Why aren't you using `Date`s?  You don't appear to be validating that your end is after your beginning, do you want a 'negative' duration?  You should be separating input from the combo box and output to the label.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could split the `hh:mm` string in hours / minutes:

```
String[] time = sunB.split(":");
int hours = Integer.parseInt(time[0]);
int minutes = Integer.parseInt(time[1]);

double decimalTime = hours + minutes / 60.0;
```

Comment: @SiddharthRout I didn't know you followed java too!

Comment: LOL no Java doesn't fall under my `expertise` but I can understand it to some extent :)